# Solving a Recurrence Relationship

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Given recurrence relationship:

$g(1) = 5;\\
g(2n) = 4g(n);\\
g(2n+1) = 4g(n).$

I feel lost because of $g(2n)$ and $g(2n+1)$.

Based on my coursebook, there is the common standard form, which can be used in order to find the relation:

$g(n) = A(n)\alpha + B(n)\beta + C(n)\gamma$

$A(n),B(n)$ and $C(n)$ are functions, $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are constants.
I suppose this form is for the case when there is 3 constants? Thus in this case the form should be
$g(n) = A(n)\alpha$?

How does one use this knowledge in order to solve the relationship?

=====

$f(1)=α;\\
f(2n)=2f(n)+1;\\
f(2n+1)=2f(n)+β.$

This is the case when I do not have a number, but a constant - how does one solve the relationship?

Comment: You can find $g(2)$ immediately from the first and second relations. Then you can find $g(3)$, $g(4)$ and so on. What's the problem?

Comment: @YuriyS, could you clarify a bit? so I can say that $n=1$, $g(1)=5$, $g(2*1)=4*5$, is that correct? Also, when one can state that the relationship is solved?

Comment: Yes to your first question. And you can find $g(3)$ using the third relation. Then $g(4)$ and $g(5)$ using the known value of $g(2)$ and second and third relations respectively. Then you find $g(6)$ and $g(7)$ using $g(3)$ and so on. In general, the relationship is solved when you introduce a function $g(n)$ which immediately gives you any $g(n)$ without knowing $g(n-1)$, $g(n-2)$ and so on. In other words, $g(n)$ should explicitly depend on $n$

Comment: You should list first 31 terms. Then you can see the pattern. Note that the 16th term to the 31th term are the same.

Comment: @YuriyS, thank you for clarification. How would one solve this case:
$f(1)=\alpha;\\
f(2n)=2f(n)+1;\\
f(2n+1)=2f(n)+\beta\\$


In this case one does not have a number, but just the constant. How would you understand the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a  contribution that is not a compact form  but may perhaps be
of some use. Supposing the recurrence

$$f(1) = \alpha,
\\ f(2n) = 2f(n) + \beta,
\\ f(2n+1) = 2f(n) + \gamma.$$

Introduce the base two representation of $n$ which is

$$n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor} d_k 2^k.$$

We then obtain the closed form (exact) by inspection which is

$$f(n) = \alpha \times 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}
+ \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor-1} 
([[d_k = 0]]\times \beta + [[d_k = 1]]\times \gamma)
 \times 2^{k}.$$

We can deduce some special values from this e.g.
$$f(2^m) = \alpha \times 2^m
+ \beta \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} 2^k
= \alpha \times 2^m
+ \beta \times (2^m-1).$$

Similarly
$$f(2^m-1) = \alpha \times 2^{m-1}
+ \gamma \sum_{k=0}^{m-2} 2^k
= \alpha \times 2^{m-1}
+ \gamma \times (2^{m-1}-1).$$